# Class Node and Class Queue, how does the "pointer" work?

Tags: class, python-3.x, nodes

So I have this code, it is working in it's current shape, it's an assignment, but it feels like none of us really understands how this works, and I really want an answer, because it feels like everytime I work with classes, it's the same thing that bothers me.
The code:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self,data):
        self.cargo=data
        self.pekareinnan=None

class Queue:
    def __init__(self):
        self.svans=None
        self.huvud=None

    def put(self,x):
        item=Node(x)
        if self.svans==None:
            self.svans=item
            self.huvud=item
        else:
            self.svans.pekareinnan=item   #What does this line really do?
            self.svans=item

    def isempty(self):
        return self.huvud==None

    def get(self):
        if self.huvud==None:
            return None
        else:
            do=self.huvud.cargo
            self.huvud=self.huvud.pekareinnan ##How does this line work?
            return do
```

If it's hard follow, pekareinnan=pointerbefore (swedish), svans = tail, huvud= head. I've tried to ask people who knows a lot more programming than me and one of them said that svans is a sentinelnode. Let's say I have a list with 1,3 and 5 in it. I wanna put 9 in there as well, what is pekareinnan, what is svans? Thankful for any help,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It helps to start with an empty `q`. In that case, `q.svans` and `q.huvud` are both `None` before you call `q.put(1)`. When you call, you stat by creating a new `Node` object containing 1:

```
item.cargo = 1
item.pekareinnan = None
```

Now, since `q.svans is None` (use `is` to compare to `None`, not `==`), 
we set both `q.huvud` and `q.svans` to `item`, so that the same node serves as the head and the tail of the list.

```
                      item
                        |
                        V
q.huvud ----->  +-----------+------+
                |     1     | None |
q.svans ----->  +-----------+------+
```

When we call `q.put(3)`, we add 3 to the end of the list by leaving `q.huvud` alone, but updating both `pekareinnan` of the old tail, then `q.svans`.

First, create the new node:

```
                                                 item
                                                   |
                                                   V
q.huvud ----->  +-----------+------+  +------------+------+
                |     1     | None |  |      3     | None |
q.svans ----->  +-----------+------+  +------------+------+
```

Next, link it to the existing list with `q.svans.pekareinnan = item`:

```
                                                 item
                                                   |
                                                   V
q.huvud ----->  +-----------+------+  +------------+------+
                |     1     |  * --+->|      3     | None |
q.svans ----->  +-----------+------+  +------------+------+
```

Then update the queue itself by setting `q.svans = item`:

```
                                                 item
                                                   |
                                                   V
q.huvud ----->  +-----------+------+  +------------+------+
                |     1     |  * --+->|      3     | None |
q.svans         +-----------+------+  +------------+------+
   |                                         ^
   |                                         |
   +------------------------------------------
```

The same thing happens when you add 5 and 9: you allocate a new node, set `pekareinnan` of the *existing* `q.svans` to the new node, then set `q.svans` to the new node as well.

---

To remove an item, we do the same thing, but with `q.huvud`. Note that `q.huvud` is the only pointer to the first node, so we need to remember what the cargo is before we update `q.huvud` to delete the node.

```
 cargo = q.huvud.cargo #   1


q.huvud ----->  +-----------+------+  +------------+------+
                |     1     |  * --+->|      3     | None |
q.svans         +-----------+------+  +------------+------+
   |                                         ^
   |                                         |
   +------------------------------------------
```

Now we can remove the head by simply overwriting `q.huvud` with the node that follows it.

```
   +-----------------------------------------+
   |                                         |
   |                                         v
q.huvud         +-----------+------+  +------------+------+
                |     1     |  * --+->|      3     | None |
q.svans         +-----------+------+  +------------+------+
   |                                         ^
   |                                         |
   +------------------------------------------
```

Because nothing points to the node containing 1, it is effectively deleted; it will eventually be garbage-collected.

Comment: Thanks a lot for a great explanation, if I understand you 1 is at first a node serving as both head and tail, when I add another number, I have to update the pointer, so that it points to the new tail. Ive heard it before, but to say that a node is both an object containing a value and a pointer would be correct? Last question, why do you want to use is instead == ?

Comment: Correct, a node contains both a value and a pointer to the next node. Using `is` is mostly the preferred convention; it is safe because `None` is a singleton, the only object of its type.

Comment: If you got time, I asked this because I'm trying to add a remove-method to my binarysearch tree. I'm looking at already done code, and I realize its hard for you to help when you dont see the code, but if you say self.left = child and self.left.right = grandchild, how does that work, self.left is only a pointer if I've understood it right, self.left.right, is that one step to the left and then one step to the right? Thanks again for helping out!